# Ways to express possession

Tags: saxon-genitive, possessive-s-vs-of

Is this grammatically correct? **The survival kit of an English teacher**.

I doubt if this should be written as follows: **An English teacher's survival kit**.

While I know the second one is grammatically correct, the first option sounds better. As far as I know when we talk about possession, we have to use the Saxon genitive.

Comment: Either way is fine.  It depends on the "tone" you wish to convey.